# C# else statement not run when file not found

Tags: c#, io

EDIT:
My problem has been solved thanks to the user Chris Larabell, thank you to all that responded.

The issue that is happening with my code is that when the said file is not present in the Desktop directory, the console will close and will not go to the else statement for what happens when the file is not present. When the file is present however, the console will work completely fine, it is just the else statement.
Here is my code that is being used.

```
if (inputDrive == "search.system")
        {
            try
            {
                string Desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
                string DeleteFile = @"delete.txt";
                string[] fileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Desktop, DeleteFile);
                foreach (string file in fileList)
                {
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(file);
                        Console.WriteLine("File has been deleted");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("File could not be found");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("search has encountered an error");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to find a file through the Desktop directory with the name of 'delete.txt' and to delete it when the user enters "search.system". the console would then say back to you that the file has been deleted. If the file has not been found, it would say that "the file could not be found" back to you through console. If an error would to occur, it would go to catch and say "search has encountered an error"

I also want to say that I am sorry if this code is messy and/or if this is completely wrong from what I am trying to accomplish. I am new to C#, and new to coding in general.

Comment: Put a breakpoint the go stepping using `F11`

Comment: It's likely that something goes wrong with `File.Delete` and throws an exception, the `catch` block is entered, prints the message and then closes as nothing is keeping the window open.

Comment: You need to learn [how to debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Equalsk: if I understand correctly - the problem is when the file does not exist - so it should not get to the delete method.

Comment: Please read what [`GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) does; it returns files **that exist**. If the file doesn't exist `GetFiles` won't return it and your `foreach` will never be entered. If you ran your code in the debugger you would have seen that. Note that searching for a single file can only return at most one file, so I don't understand what your code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @PaulF I read it wrong, I guess that `fileList` is simply empty in this case. My bad.

Comment: @DourHighArch: actually the if statement is not required - as you pointed out OP is using an array of files known to exist.

Comment: Seems to me the whole listing is not required... you only go one filename. Just check if it exists without the `GetFiles` or the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to put an `if` statement to check that the `fileList` length is `> 0`.  If the file length is zero, the file was not found.  Otherwise, you can proceed to delete the file.

Also, don’t be discouraged as a new coder.  Set a breakpoint at the line where you use the `GetFiles()` method and step (F11) to the next line.  Hover your cursor over the `fileList` variable and see if the number of items in the array is zero.

[System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are simply looking for a specific file by name and deleting it if it exists.  You could simplify your code by doing this:

```
if (inputDrive == "search.system")
{
    try
    {
        string Desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
        string DeleteFile = @"delete.txt";
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Desktop, DeleteFile);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
            Console.WriteLine("File has been deleted");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("File could not be found");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"search has encountered an error: {ex}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `Path.Combine` to join paths. By the way, I'm not sure what in this whole thing could possibly throw that `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: @Nyerguds, good points.  I have updated the code.  I had just copy/pasted the whole catch statement. ;)